# goto main corona game SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i am developing a simple corona game.
when I want to call back the main.lua using this code:

```
storyboard.loadScene( "main",true)
```

it do nothing for me.
and when I use

```
storyboard.gotoScene( "main", "fade" ,40 )
```

the main loaded but i can not use functionality of main!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the storyboard documentation available at http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/gotoScene.html, your syntax for storyboard.gotoScene() was incorrect

```
local options = {
    effect = "fade",
    time = 40
}

storyboard.gotoScene("main", options)
```

-- Moksh

Comment: i have changed it to this but not worked yet it said sceneName is a nil value !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you required storyboard? e.g. `local storyboard = require("storyboard")`
2. Have you declared the scene? e.g. `local scene = storyboard.newScene()`
3. Have you declared the 3 phases? e.g

   `function scene:createScene(e);`
   `function scene:enterScene(e);`
   `function scene:exitScene(e)`
4. Have you added the **3** event listeners to 'scene' ? e.g.
   `scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)`
5. Have you used the self.view ?
6. To change scene: `storyboard.gotoScene('#scene', {time = value, effect = value})`

Comment: Try to insert every function or piece of working code inside the scene:createScene(e) function

Comment: how to do this ? using require?

Comment: No, try to manually move every function/variable/display inside the scene:createScene function you have at the bottom of your file. You may get a result from this

Answer (score 0):

main.lua should never be considered a scene.  You never go back to it.  Your main.lua is a launch point to get you into a storyboard scene and then the storyboard scenes can go to themselves.  The storyboard code in main.lua should be nothing more than:

```
 local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )

 -- other code that needs to run outside of storyboard
 -- then at the bottom of your main.lua

 storyboard.gotoScene("menu", options) -- whatever options you need.
```

The things that should be in main.lua include system event handlers, key handlers, maybe starting up facebook and its listener, IAP initialization and event handler, etc.  In my apps I normally do:

```
 main.lua --> splash.lua -- > menu.lua --> game.lua --> nextlevel.lua 
                                                    --> gameover.lua
                                       --> help.lua
                                       --> gamecredits.lua
                                       --> gamesettings.lua
```

and those modules go back to menu.lua when they are done.